# Loop through nodes of same content type

Tags: theming, nodes

I currently have a page template set up in its page-node-946.tpl.php. `$content` is being populated by that node numbers content. I need to loop through and display a teaser for all content nodes and certain type. I need some instruction on how to do it. Maybe I've gone wrong by trying to do this with a page-node template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) for looping throug nodes. Just build Views that show list of certain nodes, then call it into your template file, like this: `print views_embed_view('VIEWNAME', 'DISPLAY_ID');`
But creating for each page one node template file is not good way for this (you will got many count of this page-node-XXX.tpl.php files, for serving all of these you will take more time, even you want to change something little), node-TYPE.tpl.php will better with more common page.tpl.php. 

p.s. Also customizing page via [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) without template have better UI.